# What are the advantages of sending timestamp in the response?

Tags: java, design, rest

I am working on REST API and it calls another service and fetch the data and return to the UI. So It does not have any direct DB interactions. Recently we added exception handling feature which uses Controller Advice to handle the Application level exceptions. A sample response looks like below:

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2021-11-01T12:14:45.624+0000",
    "status":500,
    "error":"Internal Server Error",
    "message":"No message available",
    "path":"/api/book/1"
}
```

When ever there is an error, the UI logs the message to Splunk which alreadys logs using Timestamp. So Is there really a advantage of adding timestamp to the response? Or What other advantages do I get using this timestamp field in my response?

Comment: What will the client of the REST API use this timestamp for? If you cannot think of a good use, then do not include it.

Comment: As of now, they donot use it.

Comment: To be honest, [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) applies here (Ya Ain't Gonna Need It).

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the link. Clears some confusion here.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How can you possibly know that?  In my experience this is one of those things that you don't need until you do need it and really wish you had done it all along.

Comment: In some cases - maybe many cases? - the client can get a reasonable timestamp from the response metadata.  If it ever becomes necessary for the client.  So it need not be included with the response.  It will be off by some milliseconds, perhaps, so won't directly match log messages from the server, but there is probably some additional information with each request/response that both client and server have, and that they log, that can resolve ambiguities (e.g., a session id).

Comment: Oh, here's a PRO TIP: Timestamps in logs and messages should _ALWAYS BE UTC_.  Don't even think about any alternative: If you need timestamps at all the _possibility_ that they're _not always UTC_ **will** bite you eventually.

Comment: One more minor tip:  _Getting_ a timestamp from the OS, and then _formatting_ it to insert into a log or a message can be surprisingly expensive.  If you're in a high-throughput low-latency environment - or if you're doing lots and lots and lots of logging or messaging - consider measuring that impact (and reducing it if necessary).  Formatting a GUID is usually much less expensive, for example, even though its longer.  (_Generating_ a GUID, on the other hand ...)

Comment: @davidbak The thing is that if the timestamp on the server and what you have locally are more than a few milliseconds off, it's really useful to have that information.  For example, your server timestamp is *after* your local one.  Also, I don't think that generating UUIDs is terribly expensive but if you are using version 4 (full random) UUIDs, you could get exhaust the available entropy on the system.

Comment: @JimmyJames - w.r.t. UUIDs there's frequently an API to generate "batches" of 'em.  w.r.t. timestamps being off - yes that can happen, but IMO, if you're looking at correlating client w/server it's much easier with unique session/transaction/etc ids of some kind (not necessarily GUIDs) - one principal reason is that log grovelling tools (Splunk, etc. etc.) will do a lot of work for you grouping your interactions by id, but not be so helpful if all you have are timestamps.  Of course, the ids _do_ go into the messages so you have to think about them beforehand, like the OP is doing ...

Comment: @happytohelp On a somewhat related note, make sure you are specifying the timestamp when you log to Splunk otherwise your timestamps in splunk will be when it was indexed, not when it happened on the server and the timestamp resolution is not great.

Comment: @JimmyJames - oh yeah, Splunk timestamp (default) resolution for messages is awful!  Forgot about that!  Though it usually gets messages from a single thread in the right order, thank goodness ...

Comment: @davidbak Yeah, I recommended adding a UUID in my answer.  They are nice in splunk because you can do bare searches on them which are actually faster than keyed searches.

Comment: @davidbak It's really bad if you overwhelm the indexers (seen this a lot) or if files aren't getting picked up for whatever reason.  Also having a timestamp in the message can help you see the latency on the logging.  The upshot here is adding your own timestamps is super inexpensive but can have very large returns.

Comment: @davidbak Back to the timestamps: I've run into issues more than once in my career where I found bizarre behaviors that made no sense until we realized that every machine has its own clock and you can't assume they are always synced or correct.  In terms of correlating issues, yes this is a pretty poor solution for that but sometimes it's all you've got to go on.

Comment: @JimmyJames - I agree. And I too have had the experience of getting _badly bitten_ by servers with bad clocks.  (Including one nasty nasty case of certain HP servers in the datacenters with bad BIOS code that _sometimes_ booted with the wrong time ...) I should clarify:  I do in fact believe in accurate timestamps in logging (esp on the usual server handling many concurrent calls/operations).  But I guess I was thinking about the OP's question which was whether to include them in (each and every) message.  There I have found other things more useful.

Comment: @davidbak I would argue that the cost of adding it to the response is so small that even the chance that it's useful makes it worth doing.  One use I've found it's good for is evaluating performance.  If you don't have a timestamp from the server, it can be difficult to distinguish poor server performance from poor network performance.  There are other ways to figure this out but I can't think of a more straightforward way that covers the full round-trip from client to server and back while demarking the 'legs'. Usually uninteresting but impossible to recreate once the interaction is done.

Answer (score 1):

There are of general ways a client can use a timestamp in the response:

- It can help identify issues with incorrectly configured system clocks
- It can help with identifying latency issues

The other thing I would consider here is what you will do when supporting a client when they get an error like this:

> [client] I got a 500 error.
>
> [you] when?
>
> [client] In the middle of the night sometime?

At the very least you can use the timestamp to narrow down the search in your logs.  I would recommend that you add UUID as well that you log and return to the client.  This makes it a lot easier to find things.